# 2nd Gmail account syncing only once per day

Tags: gmail, 9.0-pie

I am using the Gmail app on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ on Android 9 with 2 Gmail accounts and a Yahoo account. My primary Gmail account and my Yahoo account sync very frequently and I get notifications about new emails within 5 minutes.

However my secondary Gmail account gets far fewer emails and it only syncs once per day, in the middle of the night.  I've seen a lot of questions about this happening to POP accounts, and potential solutions to increase frequency by increasing the number of emails received. But this is a Gmail account and I should be getting push notifications with instant syncing, right?

Is there a setting to check? Or even though it's a Gmail account, do I need to write a script to send myself messages every 5 minutes?

Comment: Have you checked what sync date/time is displayed in the Android settings -> Account -> 2nd Google account -> Sync?

Comment: Do you mean "Days of mail to sync" setting? That's 30 days. Or are there other sync settings I can't find? Under "Data Usage" in the account setting, I see 1) Sync Gmail (checked), Days of mail to sync (30), Download attachments (checked), Images (always display), Enable dynamic email (checked)